# How to redirect from terminal stdin to process stdin

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ssh

My running process handles stdin by using `getchar()`. It works fine when I run it in foreground. However if I run it in background and do `echo "a">> /proc/pid/fd/0` it won't work. On my system, `/proc/pid/fd/0` is as same as `/proc/pts/0`, so how do I send to the process's stdin so that `getchar()` can see it? I'm working in C++ over ssh.

Comment: I think you might need to research termios.h.

Comment: try changing redirection `>>` to a pipe `|`

Comment: @Neo1989 changing it to | won't work.sudo echo "a"| /proc/5133/fd/0
-bash: /proc/5133/fd/0: Permission denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing-to-stdin-of-background-process](http://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process) . The solution using named pipe should work.

Comment: @user3472537 sorry I mistook the file as a program. Try this: `echo "a" | sudo tee /proc/file`. Add `-a` to `tee` if the value is meant to **appended** to the file

Comment: @Neo1989 still not working, however I found a work around using mkfifo

Comment: I believe the typical solution involves named pipes. Try to look up `mkfifo`.

Comment: Uh didn't realize that's already in the comments (the last comment was hidden from view). Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run multiple programs in background, they still have `/dev/pts/XX` as their control terminal (and `stdin`), but they are no longer eligible to read from it -- only shell or foreground task can do that. If they do, they'll get `SIGTTIN` signal that stops background process:

```
myaut@zenbook:~$ cat &
[1] 15250
myaut@zenbook:~$ 

[1]+  Stopped                 cat
```

Reasoning for such behavior is simple: multiple programs reading from one source leads to [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). I.e. when you input to shell `who am i`, shell will read `who`, background task #1 will read `am` and task #2 will read `i`.

The solution is simple -- do not use pseudo-terminals to transfer data between processes:

- Use pipes -- unnamed or named (with `mkfifo`). They are as simple as reading from `stdin`. Modern shells also provide *coprocesses* that allow to avoid named pipes.
- Use UNIX sockets in complex cases
- If you still need a pseudo-terminal, create a new one for your program with `screen` or other terminal emulator.

Comment: Oh, by the way, there's one more solution: coprocesses. Runs in the context in exactly one shell.